# How to avoid repeating multiple conditions in OR function using Arrayformula?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, operators, dry

I have this google sheets input.

| Players | Loot |
| --- | --- |
| Player1 | 4 |
| Player2 | 4 |
| Player3 | 5 |
| Player4 | 2 |

What I'm attempting to do is simplify this formula in order to get `TRUE` in a single cell.

```
=OR(B2>=5,B3>=5,B4>=5,B5>=5)
```

This is what i did so far.

```
=ArrayFormula(SUM((B2:B5*1>=5)*1))>0
```

Can this formula be simplied further and still get `TRUE` **in a single cell** when one of Loot values is `>=` 5?

Comment: Use `COUNTIFS()`.

Comment: @Harun24hr `=COUNTIF(B2:B5,">=5")>0` its great.

Comment: You want column C to say true or false on each row if B is 5 or higher?

Comment: No, @CodeCamper "...in order to get TRUE in a single cell."

Comment: @Harun24hr it seems your comment answers OP's question. Perhaps you can post this as a legitimate answer for this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the entire range `B2:B5` and check if it's  greater than `5` using `>=`. `>=` operator supports arrays. `OR` merges the values to a single cell.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(OR(B2:B5>=5))
```

`AND` can be used in a similar way.

Answer (score 3):

`COUNTIFS()` may give you desired result. Try-

```
=COUNTIFS(B2:B5,">=5")>0
```